# How to organize delayed resolution of service per scope?

Tags: simple-injector

I have a singleton object that is created at startup of application. Object has a dependency on sub-service that should be created later per scope, after the scope-key is already known.
How to register such dependencies?

```
testContainer.Register<DelayedServiceConsumer>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
testContainer.Register<Func<IDelayedService>>(() => new DelayedService(), Lifestyle.Scoped);


public class DelayedServiceConsumer() {
   public DelayedServiceConsumer(Func<IDelayedService> delayedServiceFactory) {....} 

   public void SomeMethod() {
      // I need per scope resolution happening here. If we already have service for that scope container should just return that instance. Otherwise new instance should be created for the scope
      var service = delayedServiceFactory(); 
   }
}
```

Comment: What is it that doesn't work with your current approach?

Comment: @Steven, Register<Func<IDelayedService>> requires Func<Func<IDelayedService>> as input parameter

Answer (score 0):

Change your registration to:

```cs
testContainer.RegisterInstance<Func<IDelayedService>>(() => new DelayedService());
```

For more formation, see the documentation: https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#register-factory-delegates

Comment: RegisterInstance doesn't have overload with Scope.  
But seems I found this workaround:  

~~~    var producer =   
     testContainer.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle.CreateProducer<IDelayedService, 
     DelayedService>(testContainer);
                testContainer.RegisterInstance<Func<IDelayedService>> 
    (producer.GetInstance);
            testContainer.Register<DelayedServiceConsumer>(Lifestyle.Singleton);~~~